# How to get text values to an array?

Tags: java, selenium, katalon-studio

I have set of price value and below script is getting generated a set of value set which i need to compare against. My Katalon-studio script as below (test case and keyword), how can I get those values to an array/list, kindly help.

Test case

```
for(int i=1; i<=9; i++){    
CustomKeywords.'decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid'(Integer.toString(i))
}
```

Keyword

```
public class public_equities_selctor {

    private String market_selector_selector(String navid){
        return '//*[@id="exchange_'+ navid +'"]/div[2]';    
    }

    private TestObject getequitiesid(String navid){
        TestObject equitiesitem = new TestObject(navid);
        equitiesitem.addProperty("xpath", ConditionType.EQUALS,market_selector_selector(navid),true);
        return equitiesitem
    }

    @Keyword
    public void navigatetoMainequitiesid(String navid){
        TestObject equitiesitem = getequitiesid(navid);
        WebUI.waitForElementPresent(equitiesitem,GlobalVariable.time_1)
        String abc = WebUI.getText(equitiesitem)
    }
```

Actual 
14,304 ,
1,529 ,
. 
.

Expected 
into Array list,  so I can compare those with an existing array list

my console

```
2019-08-30 10:31:54.220 DEBUG testcase.public_equities_comparison      - 1: decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid(Integer.toString(i))
8,566 (0.45%)
2019-08-30 10:31:54.424 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid is PASSED
2019-08-30 10:31:54.424 DEBUG testcase.public_equities_comparison      - 1: decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid(Integer.toString(i))
3,869 (0.16%)
2019-08-30 10:31:54.482 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid is PASSED
2019-08-30 10:31:54.482 DEBUG testcase.public_equities_comparison      - 1: decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid(Integer.toString(i))
6,606 (0.51%)
2019-08-30 10:31:54.581 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid is PASSED
2019-08-30 10:31:54.581 DEBUG testcase.public_equities_comparison      - 1: decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid(Integer.toString(i))
9,806 (0.24%)
2019-08-30 10:31:54.662 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid is PASSED
2019-08-30 10:31:54.662 DEBUG testcase.public_equities_comparison      - 1: decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid(Integer.toString(i))
2,791 (-0.22%)
2019-08-30 10:31:54.728 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid is PASSED
2019-08-30 10:31:54.728 DEBUG testcase.public_equities_comparison      - 1: decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid(Integer.toString(i))
14,304 (-0.66%)
2019-08-30 10:31:54.794 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid is PASSED
2019-08-30 10:31:54.795 DEBUG testcase.public_equities_comparison      - 1: decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid(Integer.toString(i))
1,529 (-0.07%)
2019-08-30 10:31:54.862 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid is PASSED
2019-08-30 10:31:54.862 DEBUG testcase.public_equities_comparison      - 1: decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid(Integer.toString(i))
1,847 (-0.85%)
2019-08-30 10:31:54.914 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid is PASSED
2019-08-30 10:31:54.914 DEBUG testcase.public_equities_comparison      - 1: decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid(Integer.toString(i))
5,028 (-0.23%)
2019-08-30 10:31:54.969 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid is PASSED
2019-08-30 10:31:54.970 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - END Test Cases/PUBLIC EQUITIES/public_equities_comparison
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, declare an empty array:

```
def myArray = []
```

And then edit your for loop to add the returned result of the custom keyword to the array:

```
for(int i=1; i<=9; i++){    
myArray << CustomKeywords.'decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid'(Integer.toString(i))
}
```

and add a return statement and change return type to the end of the `navigatetoMainequitiesid()` method:

```
    @Keyword
    public String navigatetoMainequitiesid(String navid){
        TestObject equitiesitem = getequitiesid(navid);
        WebUI.waitForElementPresent(equitiesitem,GlobalVariable.time_1)
        String abc = WebUI.getText(equitiesitem)
        return abc
    }
```

Comment: ```for(int i=1; i<=9; i++){
myArray << CustomKeywords.'decypha_equities.public_equities_selctor.navigatetoMainequitiesid'(Integer.toString(i))
}

println myArray[2]``` this is printing null values , and kindly tell me what is this ("<<")

Comment: `println myArray[2]` should print the third element in the array. Is it working?

Comment: it's printing as "null" :(

Comment: Thanks a lot. you are a survivor, by the way, what is this doing :-  myArray << CustomKeywords

Comment: `<<` is adding what is on the right as the last element of the array on the left.